# How to upgrade SVN server from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: svn

I have SVN 1.6 in server side and TotoriseSVN 1.6 on client side, and want to upgrade to 1.7 for both of them. I think i should start from server side, does anyone know the procedure of upgrading SVN server?

Answer (score 7):

You have to upgrade the existing working copies using the svn 1.7 client binaries.

run the following command for each existing repo.

svn upgrade

read here more about this
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Apache Subversion 1.7 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html), you just install the newest libraries and binaries on top of the older ones.

I'd have a good backup of Subversion 1.6 before I tried this.