# Want to move tortoiseSVN 1.6.2(32-bit, windows 7) to 1.7.7(64-bit,windows 8.1) is it possible..?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Want to move tortoiseSVN 1.6.2(32-bit, windows 7) to 1.7.7(64-bit,windows 8.1) is it possible..?

is there any issue with Migrating Working Copy.?

Answer (score 0):

Verify in documentation oficial of tortoise for get resolved your doubt

http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html

Answer (score 0):

there should no problem doing that follow [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html). 
make sure that you backup your things before you start.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565096/how-to-upgrade-svn-server-from-1-6-to-1-7)