# Is there any impact while we update subversion?

Tags: svn, cpanel

I have Go-daddy virtual private server. Everything is working fine but I want to update svn version 1.6.1 to 1.7.14.

I just wanted to know, Is there any impact to my server while updating svn?

Here is the URL which I have referred: [How to upgrade SVN server from 1.6 to 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565096/how-to-upgrade-svn-server-from-1-6-to-1-7)

Thanks & Regards, 
Jignesh M. Mehta

Comment: What do you mean by "impact"? Obviously Subversion will be unavailable for the duration of the upgrade.

Comment: @tripleee: thanks for the reply. Here, impact stands for any problem arise after updating svn, there will be c-panel installed and I have used svn repository on the public_html directory, so if I update svn directory then it will affect my source code or website?

Comment: Nope, pretty confident the answer to that is no. Check the SVN 1.7 release notes for backward-incompatible changes, though (but usually a backwards-breaking version would probably be called 2.0).

Comment: @tripleee: Great! Thanks for the answer. I have seen the release notes and now I'm confident to update subversion after your confident answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no impact as the svn client shouldn't be running continuously as a functional part of your website/server.

A 1.6-> 1.7 upgrade should be seamless; just be sure that you don't have any pending changes to commit (commit before upgrading). Run `svn upgrade` immediately afterwards on each working copy to update the metadata to the new format/structure.

However, you're upgrading to a version that's several years old. SVN is on 1.9.x now. I would recommend that you upgrade past 1.7 to 1.8 and then 1.9 so that you're on current software. At each stage, run `svn upgrade` on the working copies to get the metadata formats/structures updated to match.